# Почему не обрабатывается исключение IOException?

Tags: java, исключения

Дан пример программы, в которой объявляется исключение IOException, но не обрабатывается. В чем причина такого применения ключевого слова `throws` без использования `try/catch`?

Почитал про исключения [здесь](https://www.quora.com/What-does-throws-IOexception-mean) и [здесь](http://javastudy.ru/interview/exceptions/). Понимаю, что существуют обрабатываемые и не обрабатываемые исключения, но ведь в данном случае IOException именно **сhecked exception**. Так почему тогда нет необходимости обрабатывать.

Разве "описывать в сигнатуре метода" достаточно в примере?

```
public class TinyEdit {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // создать поток ввода типа BufferedReader,
        // используя стандартный поток ввода System.in
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str[] = new String[100];
        System.out.println("Введите строки текста.");
        System.out.println("Введите 'стоп' для завершения.");
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            str[i] = br.readLine();
            if(str[i].equals("стоп")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("\n Содержимое вашего файла:");
        // вывести текстовые строки
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            if(str[i].equals("стоп")) break;
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование ключевого слова `throws` в сигнатуре метода показывает, что метод сам не обрабатывает исключения, указанные после `throws`, но может их выбрасывать, и что именно вызывающий код должен позаботиться об их обработке.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите чтобы исключение обрабатывались в коде вызывающим метод то достаточно объявить `throws` исключение, в противном случае необходимо перехватывать исключения, которые обязательно должны быть перехвачены с помощью `try/catch`.