# Зачем нужен Throws в исключениях?

Tags: java

Возможно я задам глупый вопрос , но я действительно не понимаю зачем нужен throws если есть try и catch?
Ведь throws по сути ничего не делает он не обрабатывает исключение а просто их бросает
Так зачем тогда нужен throws в исключениях?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не обрабатывается исключение IOException?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808037/204271)

Comment: Если у функции есть throws, то при использовании этой функции компилятор заставит вас обернуть её в try catch или добавить очередной throws.  загуглите `checked exception`

Comment: или отправит дальше проблему

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: речь точно идет о ключевом слове `throws` в объявлении метода, а не о `throw` при выбрасывании исключения. Вообще, не могли бы Вы привести пример кода, который вызывает у Вас вопросы? Так будет яснее что именно вызывает затруднения.

Comment: Если вопрос именно о `throws`, то он сводится к более общему вопросу, который уже был задан: [Проверяемые исключения 2. А смысл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618392/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-2-%D0%90-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB)

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, есть два ключевых слова `throw` и `throws`. Они используются по разному и я о них поговорю чуть ниже.

Но сначала разберемся зачем нужны механизмы обработки исключений вообще.

Может возникнуть резонный вопрос, "почему бы не отреагировать на ошибку сразу как она возникла?" Зачем вообще нужно "бросать" исключение, чтобы потом его где-то "ловить" и обрабатывать?

Ответ на это такой: далеко не всегда часть программы, в которой случилась ошибка, знает, как на нее правильно отреагировать.

Например, программа для чата по сети (типа skype или telegram) может использовать системную функция `send`, которая собственно посылает сообщение по сети. Как работает эта функция нас как ее пользователей не особо интересует. Теперь представьте, что во время посылки сообщения, компьютер-адресат выключился (грубо говоря пропало электричество). Функция `send` определит, что невозможно послать сообщение и вот у нас возникла ошибка.

Теперь встает вопрос, что с этой ошибкой делать. Сама функция не знает, что с ней делать. Эту функцию писали совсем другие люди, они не знают в какой программе ее собираются использовать. Например, функция не может просто показать сообщение об ошибке на экран пользователю, потому, что возможно она используется в программе запущеной на сервере, где и экрана то нету, да и пользователя может не быть, так как это серверная программа, которая запустилась по расписанию, чтобы загрузить в базу данных, скажем, информацию о новых курсах валют из интернета.

Итак, получается. что сама функция `send` знает, что случилась ошибка, но не знает, что с ней делать. А кто же знает? А знает клиент этой функции, т.е. программа, которая вызвала функцию `send`. Она то точно знает, что делать. Например, показать пользователю сообщение "Не удалось отослать сообщение" и кнопку "попробовать еще раз", если это программа чата. Или если это была серверная программа, которая загружает курсы валют в базу данных, то она может послать письмо администратору и запланировать повторное выполнение загрузки скажем через час.

Вот мы и подошли к `throw`. Этот оператор как раз и нужен, чтобы `send` могла сообщить вызывающей программе об ошибке, т.е. "бросить" (или по другому "возбудить") исключение в функции типа `send` (т.е. той, которая знает об ошибке, но не знает, что нужно делать, если ошибка возникла).

`send` будет схематично выглядеть так:

```
void send(String data) {
  if (connectToTarget()) {
      // тут реализация собственно посылки по сети
  } else {
      throw new CannotConnectException("Cannot connect to target server");
  }
}
```

Теперь, что касается `throws`. Вопрос зачем это ключевое слово нужно довольно непростой. Тут я упрощенно описываю, чтобы было понятнее. А вообще есть много нюансов, которых я тут не касаюсь (смотрите многочисленные темы по поводу checked vs unchecked exceptions).

Так вот, ключевое слово `throws` указывается в определении (сигнатуре) функции и оно говорит о том, что функция может бросить такое исключение. Например, для `send` будет так:

```
void send(String data) throws CannotConnectException {
 ...
}
```

При этом, когда вы такуя функция вызываете, то либо должны это исключение обработать, т.е. завернуть вызов `send` в блок `try/catch`, либо (в случае если вызывающая функция тоже не знает, как обработать исключение) тоже объявить в своей сигнатуре, что она может бросить данное исключение.

Тут важный момент, что эта необходимость `обработать или объявить` контролируется еще на этапе компиляции, т.е. до того как программа будет запущена.

Задумка авторов языка была такая, чтобы пользователи функции, не забывали обрабатывать исключения, и компилятор об этом напоминал и даже не позволял компилировать (и запускать) такую программу.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 2):

Исключения бывают проверяемые (checked) и непроверяемые (unchecked). Компилятор требует, чтобы все проверяемые исключения, которые могут возникнуть в программе, были обработаны с помощью try-catch (кроме исключений, указанных в throws метода main, см. ниже). Но необязательно обрабатывать исключение в том же методе, где оно возникает (как в методе `foo`). По слову throws компилятор определяет, что исключение не обрабатывается в этом методе, а передаётся в родительский метод (как в `oops`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    oops();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ooops!");
  }
  foo();
}
static void oops() throws Exception {
  throw new Exception("oops");
}
static void foo()  {
  try {
    throw new Exception("foo");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("foooo!");
  }
}
```

Где в цепочке вызовов обрабатывать то или иное исключение определяется из соображений доступного контекста и архитектуры. Проверяемое исключение можно не обрабатывать, если оно передаётся по цепочке вызовов вплоть до main и указано в его throws:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  bar();
}
static void bar() throws Exception {
  throw new Exception("Barrrr!");
}
```

Непроверяемые исключения наследуются от RuntimeException. Среди них ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, ArithmeticException и [другие (см. Direct Known Subclasses)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Пример кода, который всегда выдаёт исключение, но компилируется:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = getOutOfBoundsException();
}
static int getOutOfBoundsException() {
  int[] a = new int[]{1};
  return a[2];
}
```

Непроверяемые исключения, возникающие в методе, тоже можно перечислять после слова `throws`, но так делают в редких случаях, когда чётко понимают зачем. Обычно так делать не принято.

Answer (score 1):

За тем же, зачем нужно указание типов. Чтобы компилятор мог проверить предсказуемость поведения программы.

Comment: так и без throws компилятор выдаст ошибку

Comment: Потому и выдаст, что проверяет обработку проверяемых исключений. Если бы не проверял, ошибку получили бы не вы при компиляции, а пользователь в процессе работы.

Answer (score 1):

Специфика разных языков программирования в этом вопросе отличается.

Так, например, если в C# есть метод, который генерирует в себе исключение (или использует такие методы внутри себя), не нужно в шапке метода помечать, что он может выбросить исключение.

Однако в Java решили сделать всё несколько более явным. Если исключение, которое может возникнуть в методе, принадлежит к классу проверяемых (checked) (наследуется от Exception, но не от RuntimeException), то обязательно его указывать в шапке метода. Либо же обработать внутри этого метода с помощью блока try-catch.
Почему всегда не обрабатывать сразу с помощью try-catch?

Дело в том, что часто бывает удобнее обработать ошибку не в методе, где она непосредственно возникла, а выше - оттуда, откуда её вызвали. Это позволяет более гибко определять, что с ней делать: вывести на экран, записать в файл логирования или ещё что. Поэтому метод, где может возникнуть исключение, помечается в шапке с throws. Затем это исключение будет обработано с помощью try-catch где-то выше, где будет вызываться этот метод.

Answer (score 0):

Это специфика языка. Чтобы указать что метод сможет вызвать исключение. к примеру c# не имеет такого.

Не ищите смысла. Это лишь даёт вам видимость проблемы при этом проблему это не решает. Это как вы пометили метод проблемным, от этого он менее проблемным не станет. Девиз "Предупрежден значит вооружён" - на самом деле здесь только предупреждён, а вооружаться или нет ваша задача.

Comment: Автор вопроса про `throws`, а не про `throw`.

Comment: но мы ведь можем это сделать с помощью try и catch

Comment: исправил. Может так теперь лучше

Comment: try catch блок с исключительной ситуацией. Цель отловить и обработать

Comment: хорошо,а почему тогда  public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException {
//
//            int d = 0;
//            int a = 13 / d;
//        System.out.println(a);
//
//
//        }
//
//        }

Comment: Считается дурным тоном если программа выкидывает ошибки не юзер френдли

Comment: тут выдает исключение ну и без throws тоже будет выдавать исключение

Comment: Это специфика языка Java. Ничего странного в других языках явно не указывают, что отправили ошибку к прародителям

Comment: я знаю что try catch блок с исключительной ситуацией. Цель отловить и обработать,но зачем throws если он по суди ничего не делает

Comment: не ищите смысла. Это лишь даёт вам видимость проблемы при этом проблему это не решает

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ